# [Node.js]loop insert 1000000 documents to mongodb via native driver, why node takes up a lot of memory?

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

I use the following code to loop insert 1000000 documents to mongodb,but i found node process takes up a lot of memory,my client are dead.

```
db.collection("batch_insert", function (err, collection) {
    if (!err) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            collection.insert({hello:'world', ok:'OKOKOK'}, {safe:true, serializeFunctions:false}, function (err, result) {
                count++;
                if (1000000 == count) {
                    db.close();
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: you do know that it's not a batch insert?

Comment: I don't know how node manages this, but you are creating a million closures here. Could that be a bit heavy?

Answer (score 8):

Your `for` cycle blocks event loop. And it can't go to `nextTick` and handle query results until all queries sended to `mongodb`. You need to use asynchronous way to batch insert data.
Something like this:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var Inserter = function (collection) {
    this.collection = collection;
    this.data = [];
    this.maxThreads = 6;
    this.currentThreads = 0;
    this.batchSize = 5000;
    this.queue = 0;
    this.inserted = 0;
    this.startTime = Date.now();
};

Inserter.prototype.add = function(data) {
    this.data.push(data);
};

// Use force=true for last insert
Inserter.prototype.insert = function(force) {
    var that = this;
    if (this.data.length >= this.batchSize || force) {
        if (this.currentThreads >= this.maxThreads) {
            this.queue++;
            return;
        }
        this.currentThreads++;
        console.log('Threads: ' + this.currentThreads);
        this.collection.insert(this.data.splice(0, this.batchSize), {safe:true}, function() {
            that.inserted += that.batchSize;
            var currentTime = Date.now();
            var workTime = Math.round((currentTime - that.startTime) / 1000)
            console.log('Speed: ' + that.inserted / workTime + ' per sec');
            that.currentThreads--;
            if (that.queue > 0) {
                that.queue--;
                that.insert();
            }
        });
    }
};

var db = new mongo.Db('test', new mongo.Server('localhost', 27017, {}), {native_parser:false});
db.open(function(err, db) {
    db.collection('test', function(err, collection) {
        var inserter = new Inserter(collection);
        setInterval(function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                inserter.add({test:'test'});
            }
            inserter.insert();
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: I had a slightly different issue, but your comment pointed me in the right direction. Thanx!

Comment: This approach has huge memory leaks. By inserting only 2000 entries my ram usage skyrocketed to 1 GB.

Answer (score 3):

mongodb, just like any other database, takes some time to process requests. You're throwing a million requests at it, and since nothing in your code blocks, that means that at any time a whole bunch of them are going to be queued up somewhere (most likely in multiple places, with some of them inside the driver's code, others inside node's event loop). That takes more than a little bit of memory.

If the queuing didn't happen, you'd either block or drop some of the requests. There Ain't No Such Thing As A Free Lunch.

Comment: If I understand node correctly, there are no background threads, so *all* of them will be queued before the queue starts being processed (or at the very least before the first completion callback gets triggered).

Comment: The mongo driver could be written in such a way that it does some async stuff internally when handling a request.

Comment: Okay. But the callbacks won't get executed (and dequeued) before the queuing loop is done, right?